# Controller lifecycle and emit/broadcasts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my page, I have a grid listing all articles returned by a web service. The user can go to a seperate page to add a new article and when finished, the article should be added in the grid on the other page. So when the user returns to that page, the article will be listed.

I have a service that handles the communication between the 2 controllers (one for the grid, one for the adding of articles). This service has a function called by the AddArticleController that broadcasts a message to my GridController:

```
function addNewArticle(articleNumber) {
    $rootScope.$emit('newArticleAdded', {
      articleNumber: articleNumber
    });
}
```

The gridController picks this up:

```
$rootScope.$on('newArticleAdded', function(event, data) {
          // get all article details generated by the back-end and add it to he grid
        });
```

The problem is that, when the page with the grid has been displayed multiple times already, the article is added multiple times to the grid. I assume the reason for this is because every time a new controller is created, but the old controller is not being destroyed, so the broadcast is picked up multiple times.

How do I solve this issue? Obviously, the broadcast should only be handled 1 time.

Comment: use $scope.$emit and $scope.$on so that it would not register broadcast event again and again.

Comment: You can't inject $scope in a service...

Comment: Then you can use $controller service to call $broadcast through controller

Comment: I don't really understand that. Could  you provide (a link to) an example? I don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service

```
myApp.service('myService',function($controller){
 this.broadcastEvent = function(){
  scope = $scope.$new(); 
      $controller('mainCtrl',{
        $scope:scope
      });
     scope.broadCastMethod();
 }

});
```

Controller

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.broadCastMethod = function(){
  $scope.$broadcast("callBraodcast");
 }

})
```

Comment: Why do you call broadcast from the mainCtrl?

Comment: because if you will call $broadcast form $scope it would get destroy on view change and $on will not be call multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging that I say this from a position of ignorance; would it not be easier to have the service maintain the list of articles and let the controller observe that? It would avoid the need to send messages back and forth through the scopes and have a single source of truth.

Comment: Yup, the service actually is holding that list. However, other functions on the gridController should be invoked too; just adding the article isn't enough.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the rest of the gridController code / html?